# CSS animation rotation issue

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, css-transforms

I have an animated infinite auto-scrolling carrousel. The tiles of the carrousel ares tilted to `transform:rotateX(45deg)` but they revert to `0deg` because the animation for auto-scrolling has its own `transform:`. Since the animation is a loop I want the tiles to stay at a fixed rotation so there is no stutter through each loop.

```css
.slider {
    background: none;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
    
    .slider::before,
    .slider::after {
      content: "";
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .slide-track {
      animation: scroll 5s linear infinite;
      display: flex;
      width: calc(300px * 14);
      perspective: 9000px;
    }

      @keyframes scroll {
        0% { transform: translateX(0); }
        100% { transform: translateX(calc(-300px * 7))}
      }
    
    .slide {
      width: 300px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: #17141d;
      margin-left: 30px;
      transform: rotateX(45deg) scale(0.8);
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: -1rem 0 3rem #000;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide-track">
                <div class="slide" ></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
                <div class="slide"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are tilting about the x axis and also have given perspective. If you remove the animation you’ll see the slides seemingly gradually appearing to reduce their slope. Could you describe what you want it to look like as the slides move?

Comment: i would like the slides to be all tilted at 45deg (like the first ones) during all the animation so that when the animation loop restarts, it doesn't glitch from straight to tilted. thank you for your interest :)

Comment: They are all tilted around the x axis but you have set perspective. Think of what a sheet of paper looks like tilted at 45deg and right in front of you, then a bit to the left etc.

Comment: …or just not rotated at all but skewed? The left hand one only looks as it does because it’s rotated around the x axis but out to the left. It’s sides are marginally non parallel.

Comment: I see what you mean and you are right the issue seems to lie on the perspective of the slide-track. I ran a few test but i must now find the right value for the perspective to be constant from a slide to another if that's possible. ( adding the perspective to the slide itself didn't work)

Comment: Are you sure you want rotation about the x axis rather than just a skew?

Comment: I didn't know skew existed I will try it out. Thanks a lot for your help so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `transform` property accepts multiple values simultaneously.  In your case, change the `keyframes` declaration to this:

```css
@keyframes scroll {
  0% { transform: translateX(0) rotateX(45deg) scale(0.8); }
  100% { transform: translateX(calc(-300px * 7)) rotateX(45deg) scale(0.8); }
}
```

Comment: Since the animation is applied to the wrapper (slider-track) and not the slides, the slides are not tilted at all with this process

Comment: i added a code snippet to  better visualise the problem